Android DataSnap SSL is not loaded
I have downloaded the OpenSSL 1.0.2g Android.zip from https://github.com/IndySockets/OpenSSL-Binaries. I tried both x86 and ARM.
I have attached the two *.so files to the project, like shown in the image below.
It successfully deploys, but it does not seem to use the libssl.so and libcrypto.so files at all.
The DPR file contains in the uses section as first:
System.StartupCopy;


When I enable SHA1 Filter on the DataSnap server,
I get the

Unable to Load SSL Module on the Client.

What am I doing wrong?
Client Code
procedure TMain.SendDeviceStatus;
var
  SQLConnection : TSQLConnection;
  Temp : TServerMethods1Client;
begin
  try
    SQLConnection := TSQLConnection.Create(nil);
    try
      SQLConnection.DriverName := 'DataSnap';

      SQLConnection.Params.Clear;
      SQLConnection.Params.Add('DriverUnit=Data.DBXDataSnap');
      SQLConnection.Params.Add('DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXClientDriverLoader,Borland.Data.DbxClientDriver,Version=24.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b');
      SQLConnection.Params.Add('DriverName=DataSnap');
      SQLConnection.Params.Add('HostName=' + FServerIP);
      SQLConnection.Params.Add('Port=' + FServerPort);
      SQLConnection.Params.Add('DSAuthenticationUser=' + FDSUser);
      SQLConnection.Params.Add('DSAuthenticationPassword=' + FDSPassword);
      SQLConnection.Params.Add('CommunicationIPVersion=IP_IPv4');
      SQLConnection.Params.Add('CommunicationProtocol=tcp/ip');
      SQLConnection.Params.Add('DatasnapContext=datasnap/');
      SQLConnection.Params.Add('DSProxyPort=8888');
      SQLConnection.Params.Add('CommunicationTimeout=100');
      SQLConnection.Params.Add('ConnectTimeout=100');

      SQLConnection.Connected := true;

      Temp := TServerMethods1Client.Create(SQLConnection.DBXConnection);
      try
        Temp.DEVICE_STATUS(FDeviceName, FOwner, SSID, SoftwareVersion, SignalStrength, BatteryLevel);

        SQLConnection.Close;

      finally
        Temp.Free;
      end;

    finally
      SQLConnection.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E : Exception do
    begin
     TDialogService.ShowMessage('[ ERROR : ]'
                                 + sLineBreak
                                 + E.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;


What does your client code look like that is trying to load/use OpenSSL?

@RemyLebeau : I have updated my question with the requested code .
